# Oracle update the time in a date field where the time appears in a different column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `b_hearings`.  I have two date columns: `hearingdt` and `hearingtm`.  `Hearingdt` has the correct date and `hearingtm` has the correct time.  I need to merge or update so they appear together.

```
hearingdt           | hearingtm
---------------------------------------
2019-02-13 00:00:00   1899-12-30 14:30:00
2014-06-10 00:00:00   1899-12-30 09:00:00
2017-08-01 00:00:00   1899-12-30 09:30:00
2014-08-04 00:00:00   1899-12-30 09:00:00
```

What is the best approach?  Should I add the time from `hearingtm` and put it in `hearingdt`?  Should I create a new column and add the data there.  I'm not sure how to split dates.  Here is the result I'm looking for:

```
hearingdt
-------------------
2019-02-13 14:30:00
2014-06-10 09:00:00
2017-08-01 09:30:00
2014-08-04 09:00:00
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the values in a single column.  To convert, you can use:

```
select to_date( (to_char(hearingdt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ||
                 ' ' ||
                 to_char(hearingtm, 'HH24:MI:SS')
                ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
              )
```

You can do this in an `update`.  Or as a computed column.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you @gordonlinoff for answering a handful of my questions.  You are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the time component of `hearingtm` to `hearingdt`:

```sql
UPDATE b_hearings
SET hearingdt = TRUNC( hearingdt )
                + ( hearingtm - TRUNC( hearingtm ) ) DAY TO SECOND
```

Then you can drop the `hearingtm` column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE b_hearings DROP COLUMN hearingtm;
```

Which, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE b_hearings (
  hearingdt DATE,
  hearingtm DATE
);

INSERT INTO b_hearings ( hearingdt, hearingtm )
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-02-13 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1899-12-30 14:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2014-06-10 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1899-12-30 09:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-08-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1899-12-30 09:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2014-08-04 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1899-12-30 09:00:00' FROM DUAL
```

Would give you:

```sql
SELECT * FROM b_hearings;
```

> ```
> | HEARINGDT           |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2019-02-13 14:30:00 |
> | 2014-06-10 09:00:00 |
> | 2017-08-01 09:30:00 |
> | 2014-08-04 09:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3d282e4c1b138f004dcf120c10b8424a)*